# How do I connect MySQL database from Android in Eclipse?

Tags: database, eclipse

Hi I am relatively new to Android development.

I am creating an Android app which enables user to place an order.

I have also created a fully functional website + database which includes login, shopping cart, and accumulating the total amount.

Question is, How do i use the same database that was used for my website to link it to my android app? (this should enable user who have already register themselves on the website use the same username + password and login in the android app. Also when users select the items, the shopping cart will detects them and auto calculate the total amount).

Please help me.

Appreciate it very much

Thank you.

Comment: I think you are referring to MySQL instead of phpMyAdmin. phpMyAdmin is just a web console to manage MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Have your application contact your DB. Perhaps a SOAP implementation or something of the like would suffice. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP.

Comment: SOAP would be possible, but IMO, way too heavy for a mobile app. Much more popular and lighter-weight alternatives for Android are JSON or Protocol Buffers

Comment: I don't disagree, just throwing some suggestions out there.